# How to solve with mathematical induction $\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n <3$

Tags: induction, binomial-theorem

How would you prove this using mathematical induction?

$\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n <3$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: How would *you* prove this?

Comment: I do not think that you can prove this particular inequality inductively. You have to strengthen the inequality a little bit to make induction work.

Comment: Hint : Steps with jumps : $$(1+\frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-(k-1))!}\frac{1}{k(n+1)^{k-1}}...=2+\sum_{m=1}^n C_m^n\frac{1}{n^m}\frac{1}{m+1}\leq 2+\frac{1}{2}((1+\frac{1}{n})^n-1)$$

Comment: By Tom Apostol, "Calculus" 2nd Ed., Vol 1, 1966 - no induction involved - sec I 4.10, exercises 11,12: [1] Determine all positive integers $~n~$ such that $~2^n < n!~.~$ [2] Use the binomial theorem to prove that for positive integer $~n,~$ $$\left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n  = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \left\{ ~\frac{1}{k!} \prod_{r=0}^{k-1} \left( ~1 - \frac{r}{n} ~\right) ~\right\}.$$ [3] For $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ then prove that $$2 < \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n < 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k!} < 3.$$

Comment: $\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^n < \left(1+ \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}   $   and the second one is *decreasing*

Comment: and for $n=5$    we find $\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} =  \left( \dfrac{6}{5}\right)^6 = 3 - \frac{219}{15625}$

Comment: with one sequence increasing and the second decreasing we actually have $\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{m}\right)^m <\left(1+ \dfrac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1} $   for all positive integer pairs $m,n.$